# How to specify video size in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to get VideoPlayer class to pick up on window size of the widget that's within.
It picks up on the size when used like this:

```py
def build(self):
    game = Game()
    Window.size = game.size
    video = VideoPlayer()
    return video
```

but since I'm playing the video within the Game class it won't pick up on the size automatically.
What else I can do ?

I tried sensible solution:

```
video._video = Window.size
```

and also:

```
video.on_fullscreen(self, self.size)  # a method I found in source code of the VideoPlayer class
```

None of it helped.

Comment: Why don't you add the video-Widget to the game widget?

Comment: @ThomasStrub  I've thought about it but didn't work either.
`game.add_widget(video)`  starts the video but it doesn't pick up on the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Would be

```
def build(self):
    game = Game()
    #changing size and position
    #game.change_position(x,y)
    #game.set_size(z,m)
    video = VideoPlayer()
    game.add_widget(video) 
    return game
```

Don't know the interfaces of Game()

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simpler than I thought:

```
video.size = (Window.size[0],Window.size[1])
return game
```